# Is there a way to get the position of a camera that was manipulated by OrbitControls?

Tags: three.js

So, I wonder if there is a way to get the position of a camera, that was manipulated by OrbitControls in Three.js.

I added controls to my scene:

```
this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement)
```

And now I can move my camera freely. The problem is that I want to move it freely just to find the right position for my scene, but how do I know the number after I did that? Is it possible? I looked up to the controls object already, nothing seems to change when I move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to have a variable and use `setIntreval` to constantly update the last location.

To get the position of the camera you can use `scene.getCamera();` to get the camera and then use `camera.position` to get the position!

```js
let camera = scene.getCamera();
let cameraPos = camera.position;
```

Answer (score 1):

"*...The problem is that I want to move it freely just to find the right position for my scene, but how do I know the number after I did that?...*"

You can install `lil-gui`, connect it to the camera, and manipulate it until you find the position and/or other parameters you want. Then transfer the parameters from lil-gui to the application. Then you will be manipulating `lil-gui` to find the appropriate camera position and parameters, rather than the other way around (manipulating `OrbitControls` to find parameters).

```
npm install lil-gui

import GUI from 'lil-gui'
```

Here you have example but for `dat.GUI`, which is a little bit out of date, but still works fine. Sean set z-axis only, but of course you cane set want you want.
https://sbcode.net/threejs/dat-gui/

You can check that as well
https://threejs-journey.com/lessons/debug-ui#instantiating-lil-gui